# Что такое https и чем он отличается от http?

Tags: http, https

Что такое https и чем он отличается от http?

Comment: Метка питона здесь причем? Есть метки [http] и [https], ими и пользуйтесь.

Comment: Если очень коротко - наличием шифрования. См. https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTPS

Comment: https - это http внутри tls, вот и всё

Comment: Очень странно видеть этот вопрос закрытым........вполне нормальный вопрос

Comment: @АлексейШиманский это вопрос на словарное определение фактически, а не программная проблема (например). Я считаю что вопрос и должен быть закрыт, потому что у нас не филиал Википедии, пересказанной по памяти своими словами. В вопросе нет ничего, на что имело бы смысл отвечать более чем одной строкой в комментарии.

Comment: @insolor так это же смысл базы знаний. А если придерживаться такого принципа. то в таком случае тут можно до 70% вопросов и ответов удалять.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский как бы да, но базы знаний разные бывают. Смысл stackoverflow - больше в накапливании практических знаний. Смысл википедии - в накапливании фактов. Вот этот вопрос - про факт, а не про про что-то практическое. Либо его нужно расширить, чтобы имело смысл давать какой-то расширенный ответ (что-то типа оригинального исследования, [ОРИСС](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%BF%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%8F%3A%D0%A7%D1%82%D0%BE_%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%9E%D0%A0%D0%98%D0%A1%D0%A1), которые на той же википедии запрещены)

Comment: @insolor позицию понял)) Спсб)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы задали вопрос с неправильной меткой, но всё же.

HTTPS (HyperText Transfer Protocol Secure) - это защищенная версия протокола HTTP, который используется для передачи данных в Интернете. В отличие от обычного HTTP, HTTPS обеспечивает шифрование данных, что делает их более безопасными при передаче между клиентом и сервером.

Основное отличие между HTTP и HTTPS заключается в использовании SSL (Secure Sockets Layer) или его более современной версии - TLS (Transport Layer Security). Эти протоколы обеспечивают шифрование данных и аутентификацию сервера, что защищает информацию от несанкционированного доступа и подделки.

При использовании HTTPS, веб-адрес начинается с "https://" и обозначает, что соединение с веб-сайтом зашифровано и безопасно. Это особенно важно при передаче чувствительных данных, таких как пароли, номера кредитных карт и личная информация.

Answer (score 1):

Они в принципе одно и то же самое, но **HTTPS** сервер при попытке связаться с ним вам **пошлет свой публичный ключ** — *вся коммуникация между ним и вами будет шифроваться.*

- Для этого владелец сервера должен был сгенерировать его как часть пары (публичный ключ, приватный ключ) и **цифровым образом подписать его сертификатом,** полученным от одной из «сертификатных авторитетов», т.е. от организации, которая тем занимается. Естественно, он должен был за такой сертификат заплатить и утвердить свою идентичность.

Ваш браузер знает все коренные сертификатные авторитеты и проверяет у них, если вам присланный публичный ключ действительно принадлежит тому HTTPS серверу. Затем он **сгенерирует «вашу» одноразовую пару публичного и приватного ключа**, только для этой сессии.

- Что шифровано («замкнуто») **публичным** ключом, можно дешифровать («отпереть») только **приватным** ключом, и наоборот — замкнутое **приватным** ключом отпереть только **публичным** ключом.

  Принципиально нет разницы между приватным и публичным ключом; **разницу делаете вы**, когда один из них никому не сообщите, пока другой сообщите всем.

Теперь ваш браузер отвачает — он посылает **ваш** публичный ключ серверу, **но зашифрован его публичным ключом**. Значит, никто кроме него не сможет дешифровать его.

Все нужно сделано — **сервер знает ваш** публичный ключ, **вы знаете его**. Вы (т.е. ваш браузер) шифруете его публичным ключом, он вашим. *Никто кроме вас и него не может дешифровать вашу коммуникацию.*

- Между прочим, сервер стандартно принимает «обычную» **HTTP** коммуникацию **на порте 80**, но шифрованную **HTTPS** коммуникацию **на порте 443**.

Comment: У меня есть опасение, что ответы подобного рода рискуют создать кашу в головах вопрошающих. Такой ответ описывает принципы работы немножко ассимметричного шифрования и немножко TLS, а к HTTP по сути никакого отношения не имеет — при том что само слово «TLS» даже не упоминается ни разу, что совсем уж плохо

Comment: «он должен был за это заплатить не малую сумму» — а на фоне существования Let's Encrypt это просто чушь)

Comment: "он должен был за это заплатить не малую сумму" - серт 10$ стоит

Comment: @Ruslan, проверил, исправил, спасибо вам.